# how to concatenate a string with a double in a propertygrid view ? C#

Tags: c#, string, winforms, concatenation, propertygrid

I am using a propertygrid in C# to get double values form the user, these values are diameters of circles and the user will input the diameters for example "25", but I want after typing and mouse leave the displayed value becomes like this "25.00 cm" (without quotes), meaning to add .00 and "cm" but I can't implement this as I get an error for converting double to string. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Cast the double as a string before you try to concatenate them. Use double.ToString().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double v = 10;
string s = v.ToString(); // "10"
string f = string.Format("{0:0.00} cm", v); // "10.00 cm"
```